# Once Textbox is changed, edit the Header with it

Tags: javascript, textbox

This may sound simple, and believe me I have searched.

I have a textbox, say it's got no value in it so start with, when the user enters a value/string I want it to edit my header to add value from the TextBox onto it.

Comment: if you are wondering about the rather strange looking syntax below. you may want to have a look at jquery.  it's not to hard to learn, the website has loads of examles and it will make your javascript experience in the future a pleasure

Comment: @Andrew So that code below is jQuery?

Comment: http://jquery.com/ - the code is javascript, and it uses the jQuery library, which enhances what you can do in javascript and fixes a lot of cross-browser inconsistencies. Basically it makes javascript easier to write.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, you need something like this:

```
$("#inputid").change(function() {
    $("#headerid").text($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Also, you might want to change header as soon as user types something in the input box. Then you need 'keyup' event, instead of 'change'. You can just replace the method name above.